# Separating objects and source with a makefile

Tags: makefile, posix, sh

I have been having troubles getting my makefiles to work the way I want. First off, I would like to say this is POSIX make, as in http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/make.html I am needing my build system to work with both BSDs and GNUs(Linux).

What I am wanting is a zero maintenance makefile. I want it to just compile all .c and .asm files in src/ and place the object files in objs/ and then to link everything in objs/ to a binary file.

I can do a lot, but I can't get it to separate the source and obj files.

I am ok if this requires a little built-in shell scripting (using POSIX defined /bin/sh), but I can just not get the dependencies to work right. I want it to only build the object file if the source file is newer.

My closest is this:

```
${C_OBJS}: ${HDRS} ${*:objs/%=src/%}.c
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c ${*:objs/%=src/%}.c -o $*.o
```

This has the problem that I must still specify C_OBJS=objs/foo.o and such and also it is just barely not POSIX and therefore, compiles with BSD make but not GNU make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POSIX version of make does not explicitly support file names with slashes in them, nor does it make provision for separating source files in a different directory from the object files.  And, as noted by @caskey, it does not support any notation using '`%`' characters, though it notes that such rules exist and recommends that they be reserved for use as metacharacters.

Consequently, you probably cannot do what you want with standard POSIX `make`.

In practice, you can often do what you seek with specific implementations of `make`, but the resulting `makefile` has limited portability.

Consider using a makefile generation systems of some sort - `cmake` or the auto-tools (`autoconf`, `libtool`, `automake`, etc).  Or one of the many reworkings of the basic concepts of `make`:

- scons
- ant
- cake
- cook
- bras
- ...*and a dozen I've forgotten or not heard of*...

Answer (score 1):

POSIX make doesn't support constructs like?

```
  objs/%.o : src/%.c
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o $@
```

Forgot the question mark at the end, hope that makes my comment more clear.

Comment: Is that being sarcastic? I guess I can go for just supporting both BSD and GNU make, which that seems to work on GNU make, and is I think "close" to working on BSD make..